# Get input field through javascript and use variable in php?

Tags: javascript, php, input, submit

The question says it all.
Any ideas?

Comment: Show some code. At least the JS and HTML parts so that its possible to pinpoint what could be wrong.

Comment: Hard to know without seeing the html and javascript in question. Do you not have a name property on the usename field perhaps? Or maybe you can call the php file with a get param such as ?username=Joe. Its almost impossible to help without seeing the code.

Comment: You can try below way to send the parameters from UI to JS and to post it to PHP. If you show your code , we can help better.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="text"  name="username" class="form-control search-query" placeholder="Enter User Name">
```

JavaScript

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'url.php',
            //headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data: {
                "username": $scope.username,

            },
        }).then(function (response) {
            var data = response.data;

        }
```

PHP

```
$postdata      = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request       = json_decode($postdata);
$accountnumber = $request->accountnumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not `$post_"username"`. You should use `$_POST["username"];` to get post parameters from the sever php script.